# How to inject a viewModel into a Service class using Koin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, koin

I need to use all the behaviors and attributes that a vieModel has inside a Service class
below is an example of how I tried to do it.

```
val wifiViewModel by viewModel<WifiNavViewModel>()
```

Comment: If you are trying to use a ViewModel in a service (which you cant) then you are incorrectly using the viewmodel. Abstract your logic out into a class that can be used in both the ViewModel and a Service